# Are timers supported by the Windows native API?

Tags: c, windows, timer

Does the Windows native API support timers?

I am aware that POSIX implementations on Windows support timers, but I am interested in Windows SDK APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a tricky question to answer in the context of a POSIX timer. The Window API [SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) creates a timer on a GUI thread that relies on the thread's message queue dispatching mechanism - which means somewhere in the thread you are calling GetMessage / DispatchMessage.

If you are writing non-GUI code, having to implement a message loop is an unnatural constraint :- The Windows kernel uses synchronization objects (in place of signals) as a way for worker (i.e. non-GUI) threads to be alerted to events. [CreateWaitiableTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682492(VS.85).aspx) will create a handle that can be passed to WaitForSingleObject / WaitForMultipleObjects in a worker thread.

Alternately, you can create a worker thread - implement a timer (GUI or kernel) in that, and simply call into your (obviously, it must be a thread-safe) object as the timer is signaled.

The choice really depends on exactly how POSIX-like your application is going to be.

Answer (score 10):

Yes there are timers in Win32 API.
More details you can check here : [Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632592(v=VS.85).aspx)

In particular you need to check

- [SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [KillTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632592(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [TimerProc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644907(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [WM_TIMER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644902(v=VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

It sure does: http://windows-programming.suite101.com/article.cfm/using_the_win32_timer_api

The `SetTimer` API mentioned in that article depends on the `WM_TIMER` message, which means that you have to have a message loop, which means that you (probably) have to have a window. So it's very useful for GUI programming, less so for command-line tools.

Comment: The window for your message sink doesn't need to be visible, so it can be used in any type of app.  You really can't do much with WinAPI without having a window.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the timers described above there is also the high-resolution [`timeSetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd757634%28VS.85%29.aspx) (Multimedia API) & [`CreateTimerQueueTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682485%28VS.85%29.aspx) .