# Timer to implement a time-out function

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, timer

I'm writing a Windows (Win32) program in C, which features a worker thread to process data from a USB hardware device. The thread handling all works well, however I now need to add a timer to handle a timeout function. I don't need a callback function, just the ability to start a single shot timer, and to be able to test weather it's complete without sleeping, something like this:

```
start_timout(1000);   // 1 second

while (timer_is_running())
{
  doing stuff while waiting...
  .
  .
  .
}

do stuff after timer is finished...
.
.
.
```

This would be running inside the worker thread.

I've looked at SetTimer(), and have tried creating a callback function that simply sets a global flag, then test for the flag, but that never gets set. I'm not sure if this is because I don't have a message handler inside my thread.

Any suggestions welcome.. Cheers!

Comment: Since you don't have a message pump, it's not surprising that your TimerProc isn't called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SetTimer requires you to catch the WM_TIMER event in a window and on top of that, is not very accurate. I wouldn't advise to use it.

Instead you could simply create another thread, let it do nothing but Sleep() for the specified time period (you could pass the time as parameter upon thread creation). You can then `WaitForSingleObject(sleeper_thread, 0)` to check if the timeout has elapsed.

Comment: Creating a thread just to implement a timeout is an incredibly inefficient way to do things. The OP's use of `SetWaitableTimer` is a much better solution. Please, don't anybody even consider using the technique recommended in this answer.

Comment: Hi Jim. Just for the record, I am using a worker thread which implements a  rather complex state machine, of which the need to implement a time-out is just one small part. The thread stays running through-out the runtime of the application, and is created so that I can keep the GUI nice and responsive.

Comment: @JimMischel Obviously you create the "timeout" thread once at startup, not every time you need a timeout... That would be stupid. SetWaitableTimer is someting quite different from SetTimer, which was what the op had. The former won't work in older versions of Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your reply, I had something working quite quickly. Here's a distillation of my working code:

```
#include <windows.h>

static void func(void)
{
  HANDLE hTimer = NULL;
  LARGE_INTEGER liDueTime;

  liDueTime.QuadPart = -5000000LL;    // 0.5 seconds
  //liDueTime.QuadPart = -20000000LL;   // 2 seconds
  //liDueTime.QuadPart = -100000000LL;  // 10 seconds


  hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, TRUE, NULL);


  SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &liDueTime, 0, NULL, NULL, 0);

  while (WaitForSingleObject(hTimer, 0) == WAIT_TIMEOUT)
  {
    do stuff
  }
}
```

Regards,
Toonie.