# Timer event in C for Windows 32 console application

Tags: c, timer, console, nonblocking

I am not a Windows expert, and have only wrote a couple of GUI VB programs. I do manage K&R C language and lots of assembler, and have 35+ years in embedded systems and microprocessors control applications. So I am a mostly hardware + electronics man. I know that interrupts, as used in plain, non operating systems control software or old DOS style, are no longer possible in Windows for many valid reasons. I also know that special drivers should be written and threads created if protected interrupts are to be used under Windows. So experts: I apologize if my question sounds too simple or naive. I have "searched and researched" but didn't find a *simple* solution. [Non-blocking sleep timer in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771142/non-blocking-sleep-timer-in-c) , [Timer to implement a time-out function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30126609/timer-to-implement-a-time-out-function/30128378#30128378), [Using Timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/using-timers), all use GUI or C++ or are too complicated.

I need to write a Windows32 console application that implements a large state machine, and several communications timeout timers are needed along with some other concurrent process timers, ranging from 1 ms to several tens of minutes. Sleep() won't work because the automata keeps on working while waits for these events to signal their termination. I found this solution [CreateWaitableTimer with an Asynchronous Procedure Call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Sync/using-a-waitable-timer-with-an-asynchronous-procedure-call). Should this code work in K&R C and how this code would be like ? If I am right, the callback function could contain the small code needed for the timers without hanging the program as Sleep() does. I am using MS Visual Studio 2012 as C compiler. I would very much appreciate any advice and help for a very simple C solution.

Comment: Perhaps start a thread which signals to the main thread when returned from `Sleep`

Comment: Could you give a code example in C please ? Sleep(), as I explained, is not a valid option.

Comment: It blocks, that is why you run it in a thread, which is concurrent. Sorry no code example.

Comment: Using waitable timers, running in a parallel thread, you can create something that resembles a 'base time interrupt' as done in the old MSDOS systems intercepting the clock interrupt. Of course under windows the other threads continue to run concurrently during the simulated interrupt and you have to take into account this. A method to block access to resources, i.e. memory locations, when clock code is running is to protect the sensible resources access using synch functions as critical sections, semaphores etc.

Comment: @Frankie_C , yes, this is exactly what I need **and** a small C (not C++) code example for CRT library in Visual Studio 2012. About semaphores, of course your advice noted. My application runs a large but yet simple state machine parser in the main() function. Just one thread for the timing function will do because the timing function is really very simple, just decrementing nonzero counters. The timing event could be a callback function or a portion of main() checking some shared variables (counters) to reach zero. But I need a pure C code example for CRT.

Comment: See this sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Sync/using-waitable-timer-objects. Simply put it not in main but in a separate thread and run it from the program startup. Specify the period in the `SetWaitableTimer` function to specify the repetition period. Put the `WaitForSingleObject` function in a infinite loop and your periodic code in this loop and you're done.

Comment: I forgot the synchronization of variables accesses. If your compiler support atomic variable types you're done, an atomic variable is guarantee to be accessed completely and exclusively for each read/write operation (a write in the middle of a read, and the reverse, can't happen).  For more complex operations, as large data blocks or function execution interlocks, you can use critical sections:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sync/critical-section-objects. In windows environment they are the lightest synch object for intra process synchronization.

Comment: Thank you @Frankie_C , I will give it a try, I don't know if Visual Studio 2012 supports atomic reads/writes, this is important here as I guess it is impossible to set or clear interrupts to allow the instruction to complete without corrupting data. Also, I see that everything is done in C++ because of the objects implied in the foundation libraries. But I still believe that something can be done in C.

Comment: @Frankie_C this is the part that I don't know how to do, could you give me a small code example ? `Simply put it not in main but in a separate thread and run it from the program startup.`

Comment: @Frankie_C I found this:

[link]https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5542/Simple-Multithreaded-Application-in-pure-C-Win32-a

I modified this example to match your advice, creating just one thread. It compiles and runs. How can I make this one thread run independently of main() once it was created. Right now it runs once and ends. Once the thread has its own life, it should decrement a counter to zero, and each time this happens it should reload this value and signal the final count, pushing a constant value into a queue for the parser running in main() to process it. Any idea ?

Comment: Roberto, after you create a thread using `CreateThread` function **it runs immediately and independently from main** (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread). In the main you can continue with other instructions (i.e. your state machine). See the examples in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/creating-threads. If you don't need to know about the thread life you don't have to wait for thread to complete.

Comment: Giving examples will not help unless I write your program. If you want to program inside a specific OS environment you have to learn some fundamentals first. I suggest you play a little with samples, and read functions available, you'll see that after you create a thread you cam run it, suspend it or kill it as you like from itself or from other threads. I.e. in the timed thread you can suspend the main thread so it not runs while you're running... Make some experimentation.

Comment: See this sample also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esszf9hw.aspx

Comment: Again @Frankie_C thanks for your great help. I have something running with 2 threads.Yes, one of this threads doesn't need to complete, and it works ! I am sorry that I can't show you the tiny code it takes because I don't know how to post code with more than one line length. You are right, I need to stop and study threads mechanics and your suggested examples. The important thing is that what I have running is plain K&R C compiled in Visual Studio 2012. Now that I see it is possible, it needs a deeper work and experimentation, as you kindly said.

Comment: I'm happy to have been of any help. If you want try a different, but fully C17 compliant compiler suite for Windows, give a try to PellesC (free for professional use also). You can find me on the forum where you can eventually also post code.

Comment: Excellent information @Frankie_C, nice from you to help me. I will keep you posted and I sure will try PellesC. Greetings from Buenos Aires, Argentina.

Answer (score 0):

Big state machine seems like the way to go. Something like:

```
int state = STATE_POWERUP, done = 0;
DWORD timeout;

while (! done) {
    DWORD ticks = GetTickCount();

    case (state) {
    STATE_POWERUP:
       . . .
       state = STATE_INIT1;
       break;

    STATE_INIT1:
       timeout = ticks + 30;
       state = STATE_INIT2;
       break;
    STATE_INIT2:
       if (ticks < timeout) { break; }
       . . .
       state = STATE_INIT3;
       break;
    STATE_INIT3:
       . . .

    default:
        assert(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Lee , it is a good way, but in my case I use a `for(;;) { parse( get_excitation) ;)` kind of state machine. I am sorry, I would like to format code here as you did, but I couldn't find the way.